# An inequality used in elliptic PDE

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

$$\sum a^{ij}\xi_i\eta_j\leq\epsilon \sum a^{ij}\eta_i\eta_j+\frac{1}{4\epsilon}\sum a^{ij}\xi_i\xi_j$$

The summations are $1\leq i,j \leq n$, all the variables are positive. Can anybody prove this? Thanks in advance.

$a^{ij}$ are elliptic coefficients.

Comment: @Paul yes, of course

Answer (score 2):

For $a,b\ge0$
$$
a\,b\le\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}.
$$
Given $\epsilon>0$
$$
a\,b=\bigl(\sqrt{2\,\epsilon}\,a\bigr)\Bigl(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2\,\epsilon}}\Bigr)\le\epsilon\,a^2+\frac{1}{4\epsilon}\,b^2.
$$
Apply this to each product $\xi_i\,\eta_j$.